# Limiting length of a phone number

Tags: c#, regex, razor

I want a field for a phone number to take in a maximum of 10 digits. I have the [stringlength] attribute placed but I still cannot get the desired result. Thanks to those that can help me.

On a side note, is it possible to break apart the phone number so that the area code and the remaining digits get sent out separately to a db via a stored proc?

model:

```
 public class Pharmacy
{
  [StringLength(10,MinimumLength=10)]
    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
            _phoneNumber = regexObj.Replace(value, "");
            _phoneNumber = Regex.Replace(_phoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
        }
    }
}
```

form field:

```
 <label id="lblPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>                       
 <input style="margin: 5px; " type=text name="txtPhoneNumber" id="txtPhoneNumber" value="@Model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber" />
```

Comment: You do realize that you're using `MinimumLength` in the annotation instead of `MaximumLength`?

Comment: @Barry, my mistake. I got rid of that and replaced it with MaximumLength but I get a red line stating "MaximumLength is not a valid named attribute argument".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using HTML tags for the input if you're using ASP.NET MVC? You should really use Razor tags.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { id = "lblPhoneNumber" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { id = "txtPhoneNumber", style="margin: 5px;", name="txtPhoneNumber", @Value = Model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber })
@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Also, make sure you have unobtrusiveJS [NuGet UnobtrusiveJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) for the validation. Everything else seems fine with the data annotation. The unnamed parameter of `[StringLength]` is the maximum length, while you need to specify a minimum length. You might also want to let the user know about the error, so you'll need an error message as well `[StringLength(10, MinimumLength=10, ErrorMessage="* Must be 10 digits")]`

For the second part of the question

> On a side note, is it possible to break apart the phone number so that the area code and the remaining digits get sent out separately to a db via a stored proc?

Yes, use RegEx capture groups, which you're already doing :).

```
RegEx regEx = new Regex(@"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})")
Matches matches = regex.Matches(value);
// matches[0] contains area code
// matches[1] contains first 3 digits
// matches[2] contains final 4 digits
```

[MSDN - Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I picked up this project from a guy who designed it this way. This field reads the data from the db. What I want to do is that if the user decides to edit this data, he/she can only input 10 digits. Thanks for the heads up about the error message.

Comment: Ok. If you need to do this in the View without the validation of unobtrusiveJS, then use jQuery to accomplish this using the `.change()` function. Also, your data is already existent in the model by the time it gets to the View. There is no point in time in the View that data is being pulled from the database. `$('#txtPhoneNumber').change(function() { $(this).val().length == 10 ? $(this).prop('readonly', 'true') : return; });` or something like that.

Comment: You went above and beyond @Ingenioushax. Thanks for such a detailed answer!

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help :)